# Find the area between $x + \sin x$ and its inverse

Tags: area

I am confused this problem is really hard for me . I don't know how to calculate this function's inverse but my teacher said that this can be done without finding out the inverse of the function . Please help .

Comment: FYI the function looks like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sketch+y%3Dx%2Bsinx%2C+y%3Dx, and its inverse is just reflection of the graph in the line $y=x$. Now refer to answer below

Comment: There are infinitely many regions between those two functions, and half the time one function is above and the other half the other function is. Do you want the area of just one of those regions? If so, Elaqqad's answer suffices and is a good one. If you want the signed area of two of those regions, the answer is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** The function and its inverse will be symmetric about the line $y=x$. so you can mange your calculation to computing a simple integral.

For example if the bounds are $x=0$ and $x=\pi$ then the wanted area is just double the area between $y= x+\sin x$ and $y=x$

Comment: shouldn't it be double that area?

Comment: yes you're right!

Comment: OK.But how would I know that it is symmetric about line y=x by just looking at the function?

Comment: every function and it's inverse are symmetric, and the interpretation of a symmetry is: $f$ and $g$ are symmetric about $y=x$ if and only if $f\circ g=Id$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's reasonable to take into account that the graphs of the function and of its inverse are symmetric with respect to the $y=x$. If it's nessecary to find the exact area, for example from $0$ to $\pi$, the answer is $\int_{0}^{\pi}{((x+\sin(x))-(x)) \cdot dx}=\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin(x)}=-\cos(x) | _{0}^{\pi}=-((-1)-(1))=2$

Comment: can we have a duplicate answer also! because I don't really see what this adds to my answer

Comment: @Elaqqad

Yes, they are pretty the same. That's because i actually have not noticed your answer while typing mine.